# Questionnaire for troubleshooting a phone

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way I can make this code more efficient/ more compact? It is a troubleshooting system for a phone that asks for the users input; and gives a solution based on keywords. The solutions are read of a text file. I need to make my program efficient and as compact as possible to get good marks. Any ideas?

```
#This is a function for the user to input their name and email.
#used to contact them if there solution is unable to be found.
def NameAndEmail():
  global Name
  global Email
  Name=input(' Please enter your Name: ')
  Email=input(' Please enter your Email: ')

#This is the code asking the user what is wrong with there phone.                  
def Problem():
  global Problem
  #All the possible key words 
  screen_problem=['screen','display','touchscreen','screen is cracked']
  camera_problem=['camera','lens','cant take pictures','focus']
  speaker_problem=['speaker','sound','cant hear anything']
  software_problem=['lag','slow','cant open   applications','applications','virus','apps','app','software','update']
  mic_problem=['mic','hear me','microphone', ]
  water_damage=['water','dropped in water','dropped in']
  battery_damage=['battery','charging','charge']
#This is all the possible iputs the user can ask
loop=1
while loop==1:
    print ("Hello ", Name)
    Problem=input("Hello Could you please tell us what is wrong with your phone? ").lower()

    if any( i in screen_problem for i in Problem.split()):
        file=open("solutions.txt","r")
        solution=file.readlines()
        print(solution[0])
        file.close()
        loop=0

    elif any( i in camera_problem for i in Problem.split()):
        file=open("solutions.txt","r")
        solution=file.readlines()
        print(solution[1])
        file.close()
        loop=0

    elif any( i in speaker_problem for i in Problem.split()):
        file=open("solutions.txt","r")
        solution=file.readlines()
        print(solution[2])
        file.close()
        loop=0

    elif any( i in software_problem for i in Problem.split()):
        file=open("solutions.txt","r")
        solution=file.readlines()
        print(solution[3])
        file.close()
        loop=0

    elif any( i in mic_problem for i in Problem.split()):
        file=open("solutions.txt","r")
        solution=file.readlines()
        print(solution[4])
        file.close()
        loop=0

    elif any( i in water_damage  for i in Problem.split()):
        file=open("solutions.txt","r")
        solution=file.readlines()
        print(solution[5])
        file.close()
        loop=0

    elif any( i in battery_damage for i in Problem.split()):
        file=open("solutions.txt","r")
        solution=file.readlines()
        print(solution[6])
        file.close()
        loop=0

    else:
        loop2=1
        while loop2==1:
            end=input("sorry, we are unable to find a solution for your problem. Do you want to : A) send your problem to a tecnitian and get a responce back via Your Email or B) Re write your question? or C) end the program?").upper()
            if end == 'A':
                print('Great, a tecnitian will get back to you as soon as possible with your problem of', Problem,'and will get back to you via ', Email,'Thank you for using troubleshooter')
                loop2=0
                loop=0
            elif end == 'B':
                loop=1
                loop2=0
            elif end== 'C':
                exit()
            else:
                print('that is not a valid answer, please choose A or B or C')
                loop2=1
                loop=0                       
#start of code   
print("Hi, welcome to troubleshooter 2! before we get started We need to get  some quick details....")
NameAndEmail()
Problem()
```

Comment: The code you've submitted is broken and does not run.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I only have a few quick points,

**Names and consistency:**

In general, keep variable and function names to starting with lowercase. When I see an uppercase word, I think it will be a class.

A second point here is if you are getting input, make sure the function name states that. There is no reason NameAndEmail couldn't be getNameAndEmail, and I know what the latter function does immediately. NameAndEmail looks like a class.

---

**Taking Input:**

```
def NameAndEmail():
  global Name
  global Email
  Name=input(' Please enter your Name: ')
  Email=input(' Please enter your Email: ')
```

The globals here are unnecessary, and a bad idea. What happens if someone forgets to call this function? Or worse, it causes an error? The rest of the code would either have to explicitly check for it, or pray that it will always work.

An alternative is to just pass the two values back, and have nice local variables to work with, kinda like toys that you know someone else won't swoop in and break on you.

```
def getNameAndEmail():
    name = input(' Please enter your Name: ')
    email = input(' Please enter your Email: ')
    return name, email
```

---

**Duplicated Code:**

```
if any( i in screen_problem for i in Problem.split()):
```

This code appears many times. It would be a great candidate for a function. That way, adding a new set of problems doesn't require a whole load of copy pasting

```
def is_known_problem(problem_words):
    return any(word in problem_words for word in Problem.split())
```

---

```
file=open("solutions.txt","r")
solution=file.readlines()
print(solution[0])
file.close()
loop=0
```

This is not really written pythonically. Opening and closing a file (or anything with buildup/teardown) can be done with with. One small point is that loop=0 is essentialy trying to break out of the while loop. There is a nice keyword break that will do that just fine. The code would look more like:

```
with open("solutions.txt", "r") as file:
    solution = file.readlines()
    print(solution[0])
break
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response!, the only thing that baffles me is the function part. As all the problems are different how would i get it to recognise the specific problem from one function... if you get what i mean... @spyr03 as every response in the list leads to a solution from the text file

Answer (score 0):

You should refrain from using many variable names, but I like that you used the correct convention.. If you have a lot of data, you should make use of a data structure.

If your not going to use the naming conventions, stick with what whatever convention you choose, it's a lesser evil. You should use the conventions, imagine this was maths, and you substituted + for - changing the convention. Seems like a bad idea if this is homework.

---

Seems like you have background in some other language, your use of global is very weird. It's a unnecessary bad hack.

---

To me it seems like the repetitiveness in your code is the worst problem, you should not repeat yourself and you never have to repeat yourself, and if you are repenting yourself, you are doing it wrong.

You could do something in line with this:

```
def get_problems():
    return [
        ['screen', 'display', 'touchscreen', 'screen is cracked'],  # screen_problems
        ['camera', 'lens', 'cant take pictures', 'focus'],  # camera_problems
        ['speaker', 'sound', 'cant hear anything'],  # speaker_problem
        ['lag', 'slow', 'cant open   applications', 'applications', 'virus',
         'apps', 'app', 'software', 'update'],  # software_problem
        ['mic', 'hear me', 'microphone', ],  # mic_problem
        ['water', 'dropped in water', 'dropped in'],  # water_damage
        ['battery', 'charging', 'charge']  # battery_damage
    ]


def handle_problem():
    user_input = input(
        "Hello Could you please tell us what is wrong with your phone? "
    ).lower().split()
    for key, keywords in enumerate(get_problems()):
        if any(word in keywords for word in user_input):
            with open("solutions.txt", "r") as f:
                solution = f.readlines()
            print(solution[key])
```

that take cares of all the if statements in one if statement ^^.

Comment: thanks for the reply! sorry im very new to python and thats the reason why i am not used to what you are saying.. for the code u gave me, when i type the input, it comes up with nothing. any ideas?      @Simon

Comment: did you call the handle_problem() function?

Comment: yes i did.it ask the question but no matter what i put it dousnt respond back with an answer, its just blank @Simon

Comment: Sorry, yes, I had a typo where I just defined a line variable and not as "solutions"..

Comment: ive changed it and the same thing still happens...  @Simon

Comment: Hmm, another bug. Should have taken more care answering your question. You'll have to split the user_input or else you iterate over a string, which menas that every word is a chr.

Comment: Anyways, i didn't mean to give you a solution for your homework, I meant to advise you how to compress your code.